# Merge Overlapping Regions

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of intervals, we can efficiently merge the overlapping intervals using this algorihtm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

However, if we can a set of multi-dimensional intervals, for example, 2D rectangles or areas in higher dimensions, it becomes unclear how to sort them in the first place. To be clear with the definition over overlap in higher dimension, here is an example. In 2D, [1, 6] x [2, 7] overlaps with [3, 4] x [1, 5], but does not overlap with [3, 4] x [9, 10]. That is, two multidimensional intervals overlaps iff the 1D intervals in each dimension overlaps.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do the merge in higher dimensions? I am interested in which regions are overlapping and can be merged together, instead of the boundaries or shape of the merged regions.

Comment: Lexicographically sorting may or may not work.  But the merging may be more problematic.  Should [0,2]x[0,2] and [2,3]x[0,1] be merged?  How?

Comment: The sorting issue apart: How are you going to merge the multi-dimensional intervals? If you think about rectangles: Merging two rectangles that overlap at one corner creates a bigger rectangle that contains areas that are not part of either rectangle. And the big rectangle might overlap with other rectangles that don't overlap with any of the source rectangles. In one dimension, merging is unambiguous.

Comment: For multi-dimensional intervals, the algorithm has to be different, anyway: You can't tell whether the next item should be merged by relying on a sorted list in the same way that working on a sorted list of intervals works in a one-dimensional array. Maybe algorithms for spaitial organisation, e.g. nearest neighbor search, are more useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Sort 1st dimension and merge. Then sort 2nd dimension and merge.